# Made .bat to store and use RDP credentials, hangs until RDP window is closed

Tags: windows, batch-file, rdp

I have created a batch file to keep the list of servers that i need to regularly RDP to. It's all working fine at the moment but it hangs after connecting and won't continue operations until I close the RDP window.

```
setlocal
mode con: cols=80 lines=27
:begin
COLOR 1F
cls
echo ----------------------------------[Customers]----------------------------------
echo;
echo   1) CUSTOMERNAME
echo   2) CUSTOMERNAME
echo   3) CUSTOMERNAME
ETC...
echo;
set /P rmFunc="Enter a choice: "
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------
for %%I in (1 2 3 ETC...) do if #%rmFunc%==#%%I goto run%%I
goto begin

:run1
cls
echo ----------------------------------[CUSTOMERNAME]----------------------------------
echo   1) SERVERNAME
echo   2) Back to Customers
echo;
set /P rmFunc="Enter a choice: "
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------
for %%I in (1 2) do if #%rmFunc%==#%%I goto cloud%%I
goto run1

:cloud1
cmdkey /generic:"IPADDRESS" /user:"DOMAIN\USERNAME" /pass:"PASSWORD"
mstsc /v:"IPADDRESS"
goto run1

:cloud2
goto begin
```

So with the above I would select 1 then 1 again it will open up the RDP window, but then it won't run the `goto run1` command until I close the RDP window, which is really annoying when I want to open up multiple windows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `start` commando in front of `mstsc`, this will create a new task and execution of your batch will continue.

Do you know that you can store rdp sessions in a file ? You could create a folder on your desktop where you store all those sessions, so you don't need a batch and could choose by clicking (or navigating with the up / down keys and starting by pressing Enter)